# Creating tag synonyms for some arxiv tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I suggest that we create the following tag synonyms:

- cc.complexity-theory -> complexity-theory
- ds.algorithms -> algorithms
- ds.data-structures -> data-structures
- fl.formal-languages -> formal-languages
- lo.logic -> logic
- pl.programming-languages -> programming-languages

We are migrating a considerable number of questions from cstheory to here in these areas and the tags get removed during the migration because the ones on cs are without the initial parts, so we need to edit the question after migration to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, for the CSTheory migrations. I've created the 6 synonyms you requested. Let us know if there are other useful ones (we aren't going to create synonyms for every single CSTheory.SE tag, but having the main ones is good).

Comment: I didn't ask anybody before doing this, but if there are objections, this is easily reverted.

Comment: I can see no harm in having those synonyms.

Comment: Seems like a good idea to me... no harm in it.